# Корректны ли фразы?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

Есть фразы "он открыл рот от удивления", "у него от удивления глаза на лоб полезли".
В первой фразе понятно, что удивилось действующее лицо. Во второй вроде бы тоже.

***Его кулаки сжались от этой мысли*** (кулаки ведь не могут думать?).
***Рука-предательница, сжимавшая палочку, опустилась от удивления*** (аналогично, конструкция предложения кажется мне не совсем удачной, удивляться должен персонаж, а не рука. Но эта фраза не особенно отличается от распространенной "у него глаза на лоб полезли от удивления").

Прошу вас пояснить, корректны ли указанные предложения и почему?
Буду признательна, если скажете, какое правило почитать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

про глаза, теоретически, плеоназм, потому что идиома "глаза на лоб полезли" уже означает крайнее удивление. Про рот идиома звучит "раскрыл рот от удивления", поэтому открыл рот не корректно, можно раскрыть рот, чтобы попытаться что-то сказать, можно не дать рта раскрыть. Кулаки сжались... - можно, мысль вызвала реакцию тела.

"От этой мысли щеки её вспыхнули как огонь," - Достоевский.

А вот употребляемое в современной "литературе" "щёки вспыхнули жарким румянцем" - уже тавтология. мне кажется, как будто человек не в курсе значения идиом. потому что это уже означает румянец. хотя, возможно, "щёки вспыхнули от смущения/возмущения/желания или щёки горели от мороза", то есть причину указывать корректно, также как и сжимать кулаки или опускать руки от мысли(по причине мысли).

Comment: *У него от удивления глаза на лоб полезли*. Не думаю, что здесь тавтология. См. значения: **Глаза на лоб лезут (полезли)** — у кого. Разг. Кто-л. приходит в состояние крайнего удивления, недоумения, испытывает сильную боль, потрясение (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/16445/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0). *Валидол сосал, **глаза на лоб лезли**, когда тащил лодку по речке, и вот крах жизни* (В. П. Астафьев. Капля). *...но русалка внезапно схватила ее за руку и принялась щекотать, да так, что у Дуси **глаза на лоб полезли*** (Дмитрий Емец. Таня Гроттер и магический контрабас).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова глаза на лоб полезли - это идиома которая может обрамлять некое повествование, украшение. Вводить избыточное объяснение - "от удивления", например, убивает весь шарм идиомы. Русалка принялась щекотать, так что у Дуси глаза на лоб полезли - вполне достаточный вывод из предыдущего повествования не требующий дополнительного разъяснения идиомы, то есть текст составлен грамотно. А если идиома требует дополнительного разъяснения, это как объяснять, в чем юмор анекдота, что чаще всего выдает неумение рассказывать анекдоты или неуместность шутки.

Comment: Ну не знаю... Возможно, Вы в чем-то и правы. Но объяснения "глазовылезания" присутствуют очень часто. По-быстрому (без авторства): *У «последнего» глаза на лоб лезут от стараний. От боли глаза на лоб лезут. Когда глаза на лоб полезли у меня от этого кощунственного и нелепого требования... У Олега глаза на лоб полезли от такой жадности. ...так, что у Звягина глаза на лоб полезли от боли. Беседую я тут иногда с хулиганьем, так от их цинизма глаза на лоб лезут!.. ...пишет так, что глаза на лоб лезут от восторга и удивления.  ...у меня от изумления вылезли бы глаза на лоб...*

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова мне просто кажется, что это образное выражение для обозначения реакции на происходящее, похожей на удивление, восторг и тп, но в один ряд ставить эти слова, значит заниматься повторением одного и того же. "Я плачу от грусти" - такого рода плеоназмы, если бы это было  "плачу от радости" - другое дело, но тут повторение уже обозначенной реакции, так что "пишет так, что глаза на лоб лезут от восторга и удивления" - "...восторга и удивления" это плеоназм. Вспомнил это слово) раньше думал, что все тавтология.